# Finding all sentences using regex those have words less or equal to 2

Tags: python, regex

I have tried many regex to find all sentences which contain only words equal or less than two words, the word should be something like:
Hi! or  This or (MY NAME) or (!see) or any combinations of all english characters+symbols like ?:!#,@ or numbers:

I tried :

```
(\n|\r)\s*\w+[^\w]*\w*[^\w]*\w*[^\w]*(\n|$)+
```

and

```
\n\s*\w+
```

and also ^(\S+\s?)  does not work.

and many
but I could not get the right result
http://prntscr.com/84db2a

Answer (score 0):

#### If you're using [this version of regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module, then the code below will work.

That one has the `overlapped=True` feature that is essential for the regex code below. It also matches the first sentence (if it has only two words). Once again, you must be using the `regex` library linked above - it has almost the same functionality provided by the builtin `re` module.

```
import regex


data = ("This sentence has a few words. This too. Hello world. This has four "
        "words. This doesn't. This one has five words.")
found = regex.findall(r"^([^\s]+\s*[^\s]+)\s*\.|\.\s*([^\s]+\s+[^\s]+)\s*\.", 
                      data, overlapped=True)

for group in found:
    for sentence in filter(None, group):
        print(sentence)
```

---

The code above will work in Python's builtin `re` module too, but if two adjacent sentences happens to be made of two words, only one of them will be matched.

---

Here's a breakdown of the code from regex101.com:

```
1st Alternative: ^([^\s]+\s*[^\s]+)\s*\.
    ^ assert position at start of the string
    1st Capturing group ([^\s]+\s*[^\s]+)
        [^\s]+ match a single character not present in the list below
            Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
            \s match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
        \s* match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
            Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
        [^\s]+ match a single character not present in the list below
            Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
            \s match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
    \s* match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
        Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    \. matches the character . literally
2nd Alternative: \.\s*([^\s]+\s+[^\s]+)\s*\.
    \. matches the character . literally
    \s* match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
        Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    2nd Capturing group ([^\s]+\s+[^\s]+)
        [^\s]+ match a single character not present in the list below
            Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
            \s match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
        \s+ match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
            Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
        [^\s]+ match a single character not present in the list below
            Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
            \s match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
    \s* match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
        Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    \. matches the character . literally
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you have to use regular expressions? I think you can accomplish this by using:

```
sentence = 'This is a sentence'
words = sentence.split()
if len(words)>2: 
    # Do something
else:
    #Do something else
```

If you have a paragraph and want to find sentences you can split it to several sentences using sentences = paragraph.split('.') and then loop through to find the sentences that have more than 2 words.

Comment: I have used the following Python code, but no correct results:
strData=re.sub(r'^(\s*\S+(\s|$)){0,3}$',"\r\n",strData)

Comment: For regex I think @Kasramvd have a pretty simple answer. You can solve your issue without using regex, as shiwn in my answer

Comment: but I need to use RegEx, sorry

Comment: Why have you used {0,3} in  strData=re.sub(r'^(\s*\S+(\s|$)){0,3}$',"\r\n",strData), shouldn't it be {0.2}

Comment: does n't make sense, because 3>2 and it should at least find more results, but here there is no results at all

Comment: I still have a problem